# An integral domain that is not a principal ideal domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

A principal Ideal domain is an integral domain D in which every ideal in D can be generated by an element in D.

The polynomial in x of integer coefficient $\mathbb{Z}\left [ x \right ]$ is an integral domain. But why is it not a principal ideal domain?

Comment: You should make a better searching before asking questions, specially if these are very common.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* Is the ideal $(2,x)$ principal?

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/a/563828/589.